# Status Report - Multiple projects

Tags: communication

I publish status report on weekly basis for multiple projects. Normally I uses different tabs for each project in MS Excel.

To make it more effective, I want to publish project updates in email against constraints like scope, cost, resources risks etc.

Can anybody help me with the email sample please?

Comment: Please include an example of what you have tried, and explain why the information you've tried to present insufficient for your purposes.

Comment: possible duplicate - [What makes an effective email status report? Why?](http://pm.stackexchange.com/q/2890/167)

Answer (score 2):

I observed that people don't read emails, they scan for information, therefore I don't think that you should add anything to the email.

If I were you, I would create something like this:

Subject: [Weekly project report] projects with problems: prj1, prj2, etc.

Body: <link to the excel sheet>

With this approach you can help them figuring out which projects need their attention, and if they are interested, they'll click on the link for sure. Don't do anything twice (writing the excel and the mail)